# Regularity of a function from asymptotics of its Fourier transform?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-transform

I know that if $f(t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^k(\mathbb{R})$ then we must have $\hat{f}(s)=o(s^{-k})$ for the Fourier transform. Is there some sort of converse to this statement?

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be such that  $\hat{f}=o(s^{-k})$, What can we conclude about the regularity of $f$?

I'm willing to replace $o(s^{-k})$ with $o(s^{-k-\epsilon})$ for some small $\epsilon > 0$ if that makes a big difference.

Comment: Something in this direction: If $\hat f, s^k \hat f\in L^2$, then $f\in H^k(\mathbb{R})$, the Sobolev space of order $k$. However, this only guarantees weak differentiability. One has $H^k\hookrightarrow C^\alpha$ for $k>\alpha+\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @MaoWao This was the motivation for the question in fact. Maybe i should write it more explicitly. What's nice about the $L^2$-case is that say $V$ is a vector space with volume form $dx$ and $d\xi$ the induced volume form on $V^*$ then fourier transform is an actual equivalence between $H^s(V,dx)$ and $L^2(V^*,<\xi>^s d \xi)$ where $<\xi>= (1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$. In the $L^1$-case things seems to be much more intricate...

Comment: You are looking for the [Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(approximation_theory))-Jackson theorem. Have also a look at the tenth section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), pages 131+.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry of i'm being thick here but I don't see the relation...

Comment: @SaalHardali: the Fourier transform can be seen as a limit Fourier series over the interval $[-L,L]$ with $L\to +\infty$.

Comment: related post on Math Overflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201144/about-trigonometric-series-of-the-lip-alpha-class/201202#201202

Comment: Try $\hat{f}=\xi/(1+|\xi|^2)$, the function $f$ decays exponentially, should be bounded and with a jump at the origin, so in $L^1$ but not in $C^0$, even though $\hat{f}=o(1)$. The relation between regularity and decay is a very hard question.